# Access (File.Copy) to a shared file fails in iOS 13

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, ios13

I am using the method

```
File.Copy(url.Path, localAppDataPathWithFile)
```

in the method OpenUrl in the class AppDelegate.cs (I use Xamarin for development). 
This was working in iOS 12 and below unfortunately with iOS 13 I get the fowlloing exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads/catalog.zip does not exist
```

When I check before if the file exists ( File.Exists(url.Path) ) I get true.

Does anyone has an idea how I can fix it or what changed with iOS 13?

Comment: The  `File.Copy` works fine on my side(iOS 13.0) .What is  `localAppDataPathWithFile` in your project ? It seems it is null in your new device .It works on old device maybe because it has crash . You can provide a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Thanks for the information and offer. I created a new project to share it you but I could not reproduce the behavior. The good thing is that code is correct. I look more detailed in the app setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem with setting the info.plist key “LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace” from true to false.